# Simplifying the cross and dot product

Tags: vector-analysis

Let A and B be arbitrary vectors.

simplify

1. $(a+2b)\cdot(2a-b)$

I did

$(2a\cdot a)-(a\cdot b)+(2a\cdot b)-2(b\cdot b)$

$2[a^2]+ab-2[b^2]$  would this be correct

2.$(a+2b)\times(2a-b)$

$(2a\times a)-(a\times b)+(2a\times b)-2(b\times b)$ and since a vector cross product itself zero.

=$a\times b$

but I am not sure if this be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand what you did. For 1. you just need to expand the product like it were an ordinary one:
\begin{equation}
(a+2b) \cdot(2a-b)=a\cdot 2a- a\cdot b+ 2b\cdot 2a -2 b\cdot b
=2(||a||^2-||b||^2)+3a\cdot b
\end{equation}
For 2., again expanding the product and using the fact that for any two vectors $a$, $b$ one has $a\wedge a=0$, $a\wedge b=-b\wedge a$
\begin{equation}
(a+2b)\wedge(2a−b)=0-a\wedge b+4b\wedge a+0
=-5a\wedge b
\end{equation}

Comment: yes this makes sense

Comment: In the first expansion, where does the 3a . b come from? I was grouping them as (a . 2a - 2b . b) + (2a . 2b - a . b), which I thought simplified to 2(||a||^2 - ||b||^2) + a . b

edit: wait, I see my mistake... 2b . 2a becomes 4a . b, which is 3a . b after subracting the a . b

thanks!